# Finding a string and subsequent characters in a text file using SHELL

Tags: string, shell, sed, scripting

I have a text file of the following format:

```
Value1=some string-1
Value2=some string-2
Value3=some string-3
Value4=some string-4
Value5=some string-5
Value6=some string-6
```

If I need to find the value for `Value6` and print out `some string-6` how would I do that in SHELL script?

```
if grep -qs "Value6" Test.txt
then
  print some string-6
fi
```

How would I print `some string-6` here?

Answer (score 0):

The easy way is with `grep` and `sed`. Example:

```
grep Value6 file | sed -e 's/^.*[=]//'
```

**Example Input**

```
$ cat tmpf
Value1=some string-1
Value2=some string-2
Value3=some string-3
Value4=some string-4
Value5=some string-5
Value6=some string-6
```

**Use/Output**

```
$ grep Value6 tmpf | sed -e 's/^Value6[=]//'
some string-6
```

Note, you can also do this in a single set call:

```
$ sed -n 's/^Value6[=]//p' < tmpf
some string-6
```

Regardless which method you use, to save the resulting string to a variable, you can use *command substitution*

```
myvar=$(sed -n 's/^Value6[=]//p' < tmpf)
```

or the older (and now less used) backticks variant

```
myvar=`sed -n 's/^Value6[=]//p' < tmpf`
```

Comment: `sed` is a superset of `grep`; so this is a [useless use of `grep`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep).

Comment: Also, without proper anchoring, this will extract nothing from `=Hello, this is Value6` and the wrong thing from `Value1=not at all like Value6`

Comment: Yes, you are correct, but when you talk about solutions that *suppress pattern space* to folks who are just learning to parse, it sometimes makes their eyes roll back in their heads. I added the pure `sed` solution.

Comment: Is there a way I can save it to a variable?

Comment: Sure `myvar=$(sed -n 's/^Value6[=]//p' < tmpf)` is all it takes. I'll add it to the answer.